# Rails 3 ajax update partial doesnt work without page refresh

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, renderpartial

I'm working on a Rails 3 shopping cart.  I've a catalog page that displays all products and one partial that gives a gist of the shopping cart.  So whatever product a user adds to the cart is displayed in this shopping cart partial.  Now, this ain't working.  I've to hit refresh after adding a product to cart, otherwise the partial doesn't update.

Here's my code:

Cart_Controller add method

`def add`
`@cart = user_cart`
 `@deal = Deal.find(params[:id])`
  `@item = @cart.add(params[:id])`
   `flash[:notice] = "Added #{@deal.deal_name} to cart"`
    `@cart = user_cart`
    `respond_to do |format|`
     `format.html{ redirect_to root_path}`
     `format.js`
    `end`

add.js.erb

`$("#shopping_cart").replace_html("<%=escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'cart', :locals => {:cart => @cart}))%>");`

Products page

`<div id="shopping_cart">`
  `<%=render :partial => 'cart/cart',`
   `:locals => {:cart => user_cart}%>`
    `<%end%>`
`</div>`

`<%=link_to "Add to Cart",{:action => 'add', :id => deal.id}, :remote => true%>`

This is what I see in my logs:

Started GET "/cart/add/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-07-02 18:04:38 -0700
  Processing by CartController#add as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"2"}
Rendered cart/_cart.html.erb (9.6ms)
Rendered cart/add.js.erb (11.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 274ms (Views: 23.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Please help me with this.

Comment: You using prototype or jquery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$("#shopping_cart").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'cart', :locals => {:cart => @cart})).html_safe %>");
```