# Ajax create action: partial doesn't update without a page refresh

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a text field in a form_tag on my index page that should create a new "gallery" with ajax. Unfortunatly my partial (which loops through all the galleries) doesn't update without a page refresh.

If I submit two times the form it renders feed until the next to last.

I saw several SO posts but it doesn't seem to give me any answer in this case:

[rails-3-ajax-update-partial-doesnt-work-without-page-refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560592/rails-3-ajax-update-partial-doesnt-work-without-page-refresh)

[rails-3-ajax-newsfeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532040/rails-3-ajax-newsfeed)

Please see my code:

### Controller

#### controllers/admin/galleries_controller.rb

```
def create
  @galleries = Gallery.all
  @gallery = Gallery.create(:name => params[:name])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @gallery.save
      format.html { redirect_to admin_galleries_path }
      format.js
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Gallery failed to save."
      format.html { redirect_to admin_galleries_path }
    end
  end
end
```

### Views

#### create.js.erb

```
# alert("ajax works"); rendered the alert box correctly
$("#galleries").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(@galleries)) %>");
```

#### admin/galleries/index.html.erb

```
<%= render "form" %>
<ul id="galleries">
  <%= render @galleries %>
</ul>
```

#### admin/galleries/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(admin_galleries_path, :method => :post, :remote => true) do %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Create") %>
<% end %>
```

#### admin/galleries/_gallery.html.erb

```
<li><%= gallery.name %></li>
```

### logs

```
Rendered admin/galleries/_gallery.html.erb (0.6ms)
Rendered admin/galleries/create.js.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 7.9ms | ActiveRecord: 3.6ms)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to swap these two lines:

```
    @galleries = Gallery.all
    @gallery = Gallery.create(:name => params[:name])
```

Otherwise, `@galleries` will not include the newly created `Gallery`.